# Provisioning Profile key will change after renew / expired - renew

Tags: ios, swift

Provisioning Profile have key and key chain is depended on it. I want to know when key will change.

> 1. Key will change after renew Provisioning Profile .
> 2. Key will change after Provisioning Profile expired then it will renew after some time.
> 3. Renew expired Provisioning Profile form other system or credit card.

Answer (score 1):

- IF you renew the private KEY (e.g. you lost your old one) ALL will need to be renewed (the KEY doesnt expire)
- IF the Certificate expires, you need to renew the Profision profile

---

certificates expire (can become invalid due to key change too)... THAT will invalidate the provision profiles of existing apps and also in xcode

=> update your provision profiles in xcode and rebuild apps if needed (not store apps of course. just adhoc builds)

Comment: tnx for answer Daij-Djan , Plz make it simple , " If i renew my expired Provisioning profile, Can i get my previous Provisioning Profile Key ? "

Comment: Simple: yes IF you keep the Same Mac. The key is in the